# Creating a Search Button (Double cannot converted to String)

Tags: java, jframe

```
private void searchProduct()
{ 
try {
     Product p = new Product();
     //Read data
     p.setId(Double.parseDouble(textID.getText()));

     //Display data
     textDescription.setText(String.valueOf(p.getDescription()));
     textPrice.setText(String.valueOf(p.getUnitPrice()));
     textUOM.setText(String.valueOf(p.getUnitOfMeasurement()));
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.frame, "ID must be number", "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} 
}
```

Hello recently I tried to put a button "Search" to find a product than equals to ID, but I don't know how to parse the ID than comes from the product class, I have a error.

Comment: Also consider using a `JFormattedTextField` which has support for handling numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the textID.getText() actually is a parseable double string? For instance "10.1" do but "10.1 " no.

Always I did this kind of conversion I use [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to remove this extra white spaces as follow:

```
String stringValue = textID.getText();
if(stringValue != null) {
    stringValue = stringValue.trim();
}
double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(stringValue);
```

Se here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String- how to avoid NumberFormatException using a regular expression to text you string before try to convert it to double.

Comment: In the case of `JTextField` (and in fact just about any text component based on `Document`), it will never return `null`, not since Java 1.4 or there abouts